# How can I open the lid of my sump pit?

Tags: sump-pump

I have two sump pumps in my basement. Please see the pictures. I guess pump-1 is the primary pump, located in the big room with AC/furnace/boiler, and pump-2 is the secondary pump located in a small room.

Recently sump pump-2 has some water on top of the pit lid. I saw the water on 12/24/2022, when there was strong wind and we lost power a few times. Power was back in a few seconds and every time we got power back we heard very noisy alarms.

The water has been there for over one week and I guess the pump is dead (the house was built in 2011 so the pump is 11 years old). There is power in the wall outlet. I unplug and plug back in and there is no reaction. I am not familiar with the sump pumps; how do I open the lid of the pit?
Should I clean around all the screws and remove these screws if I want to open the lid, check the pump and replace it? I checked youtube videos and all the sump pumps there are like the sump pump-1.

Thank you for your suggestions.

[image]

[image]
[image]

**Update**

I contacted the inspector who inspected the home a few months ago and was told this is a sewer ejector pump. He also told me to try separate the two pieces of plug, and plug in the pump's power cord directly. I tried, and pump worked, but it never stopped. I put them together and plugged back in. It seems I had a bad switch and need to replace the switch.

[image]

Comment: Pump 2 has a water level sensor, check that it works

Comment: Not necessarily primary/secondary.  Could be they collect water from different parts of the basement, perhaps half/half.  Why are there two pipes from each one?  Where do all the pipes go?

Answer (score 1):

The inner circle has the same bolts and will allow you to remove / replace the pump without messing with the overall lid / vent / discharge.